# How to distribute data across different nodes in cassandra cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, distributed-computing, distributed

I have setup a multinode cassandra cluster with two different nodes with all required configurations i.e cluster_name , endpoint_snitch , seeds , auto_bootstrap etc.
I am using datacenter as dc1 for both nodes. I created keyspace using -

```
CREATE KEYSPACE dcTest WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 2 };
```

Now , when I start both nodes and try entering data in database , it creates replica on both nodes. i.e if I create 4 rows in table , it copies all 4 rows on another node also. I want this data to get distributed across nodes. i.e two on one node and two on another.

Is it achieved by configuring keyspace? Am I missing anything?

Nodetoll status -

```
 nodetool -p 7199 status cassandrareplication1
    Datacenter: dc1
    ===============
    Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.45.123.123  35.01 MB   256          50.3%             8c529955-c42a-4629-dfgh-0666a444acbb  rack1
UN  10.45.123.124  225.4 KB   256          49.7%             eddf1039-d803-4d61-dfse-1ce0ec3782a9  rack1
```

Comment: Can you please provide the output of the command `nodetool status`?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson Updated with nodetool status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replication factor 1, not 2. This will mean all your data in this keyspace will be replicated once within this datacenter. With 2 as replication factor it will be replicated twice, 3 thrice and so on.

Comment: altered keyspace for replication factor 1 , still makes the replica for all rows on both nodes. Updated nodetool status above.

Comment: after changing replication factor, run the `nodetool repair -full` on all nodes...

Comment: @user7866584 Do you use different partition keys? You can use `nodetool getendpoints <key>` to find out what nodes replicate data for that partition key.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson I have only one primary key . nodetool getendpoints give 10.45.123.123 as node

Comment: @user7866584 If you only use one primary key that would explain why all data is on the same node since it's the primary key that decides which node should replicate the data. To get a data distribution you need to use different keys.

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson so primary key should be a combination?

Comment: @user7866584 I recommed reading this: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 Replication means you want 2 copies of your data into datacenter henceforth Cassnadra will put 1 full copy of data on each node to satisfy 2 RF.
to achieve your goal you may want to have 1 RF and 2 nodes so Cassandra can distribute data among nodes.
you can alter keyspace using

```
Alter KEYSPACE dcTest WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 1 };
```

Don't forget to run nodetool repair with -full option after that.